# Xtend syntax clarification

Tags: java, syntax, xtend

I'm trying to 100% understand that the following Xtend syntax means:

```
        myVar.addSelectionListener(
           [MultiSelectionEvent<String> event |
               println(event.toString)
           ]
        )
```

- myVar is a *com.vaadin.ui.CheckBoxGroup* class
- the addSelectionListener assume to receive a
  *com.vaadin.event.selection.MultiSelectionListener* interface

When implementing the *MultiSelectionListenener*, one has to implement a *selectionChange* method which itself takes a *MultSelectionEvent* object as parameter.

I understand that in my above code, I'm providing the implementation inline in my code. But could anyone provide more details about the syntax?

For example, when do we use *[ ]*, or *|* in Xtend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Xtend's lambda syntax. So in Java you would write:

```
    myVar.addSelectionListener(
       (MultiSelectionEvent<String> event) -> {
           println(event.toString)
       }
    );
```

Xtend simply replaces `(params)=>{code}` with `[<params>|<code>]`.